# Compactness criterion for subsets in a fractional sobolev space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

The compactness criterion of frechet kolmogorof gives necessary and sufficient conditions on when a set in $L^p$ is compact.

Given a set of function in a Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$ one can apply that theorem to the set and all its weak derivatives up to order $k$ to obtain compactness.

I wonder if there is a established theorem that gives compactness criterions on a subset of a fractional sobolev space.